# Why does `numpy.ndarray.view` ignore a previous call to `numpy.ndarray.newbyteorder`?

Tags: python, numpy, binary, endianness

I have a NumPy array with one element of data type `uint32`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([123456789], dtype=np.uint32)
>>> a.dtype.byteorder
'='
```

Then, I can choose to interpret the data as little-endian:

```
>>> a.newbyteorder("<").dtype.byteorder
'<'
>>> a.newbyteorder("<")
array([123456789], dtype=uint32)
```

Or as big-endian:

```
>>> a.newbyteorder(">").dtype.byteorder
'>'
>>> a.newbyteorder(">")
array([365779719], dtype=uint32)
```

Where the latter returns a different number `365779719` as my platform is little-endian - and therefore has been written to the memory in little-endian order.

Now, what's unexpected for me is the fact that a following appended call to `view` seems to be unaffected by this interpretation:

```
>>> a.newbyteorder("<").view(np.uint8)
array([ 21, 205,  91,   7], dtype=uint8)
>>> a.newbyteorder(">").view(np.uint8)
array([ 21, 205,  91,   7], dtype=uint8)
```

I would have expected the numbers to be the other way round for the big-endian byte order. Why doesn't this happen? Doesn't `view` view the data "through" the `newbyteorder` method?

By the way: if I use `byteswap` instead of `newbyteorder` and therefore copy and change the bytes in the memory, I obviously get the desired result:

```
>>> a.byteswap("<").view(np.uint8)
array([ 21, 205,  91,   7], dtype=uint8)
>>> a.byteswap(">").view(np.uint8)
array([  7,  91, 205,  21], dtype=uint8)
```

However, I don't want to copy the data.

Comment: From `newbyteorder` method for an array says it's equivalent to a view with a different `dtype` (see its docs).

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, I read that in the other answer below, too. However, this doesn't really help because I would have thought two consecutive calls to `view` are possible as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [280]: a = np.array([123456789, 234567891, 345678912], dtype=np.uint32)

In [282]: a.tobytes()
Out[282]: b'\x15\xcd[\x07\xd38\xfb\r@\xa4\x9a\x14'

In [284]: a.view('uint8')
Out[284]: 
array([ 21, 205,  91,   7, 211,  56, 251,  13,  64, 164, 154,  20],
      dtype=uint8)
```

This is the same as `a.view('<u1')` and `a.view('>u1')` since endedness doesn't matter with single bytes.

```
In [291]: a.view('<u4')
Out[291]: array([123456789, 234567891, 345678912], dtype=uint32)
In [292]: a.view('>u4')
Out[292]: array([ 365779719, 3543726861, 1084529172], dtype=uint32)
```

A view depends entirely on the data, not on the current (last) view:

```
In [293]: a.view('<u4').view('u1')
Out[293]: 
array([ 21, 205,  91,   7, 211,  56, 251,  13,  64, 164, 154,  20],
      dtype=uint8)
In [294]: a.view('>u4').view('u1')
Out[294]: 
array([ 21, 205,  91,   7, 211,  56, 251,  13,  64, 164, 154,  20],
      dtype=uint8)
```

About the idea of reshaping and reversing:

```
In [295]: a.view('u1').reshape(-1,4)
Out[295]: 
array([[ 21, 205,  91,   7],
       [211,  56, 251,  13],
       [ 64, 164, 154,  20]], dtype=uint8)
In [296]: a.view('u1').reshape(-1,4)[:,::-1]
Out[296]: 
array([[  7,  91, 205,  21],
       [ 13, 251,  56, 211],
       [ 20, 154, 164,  64]], dtype=uint8)
```

But I can't change the view (to `u4`) of this array because it isn't contiguous:

```
In [297]: a.view('u1').reshape(-1,4)[:,::-1].view('<u4')
....
ValueError: To change to a dtype of a different size, the array must be C-contiguous
```

Look a bit more at the properties of this reversed array:

```
In [298]: a1 = a.view('u1').reshape(-1,4)[:,::-1]
In [299]: a1.flags
Out[299]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  ....
In [300]: a1.strides             # reversing is done with strides
Out[300]: (4, -1)
```

The 2 arrays share the same databuffer.  `a2` just starts at a different byte:

```
In [301]: a.__array_interface__['data']
Out[301]: (32659520, False)
In [302]: a1.__array_interface__['data']
Out[302]: (32659523, False)
```

I can't do an inplace shape change of `a1`:

```
In [304]: a1.shape = (12,)
...
AttributeError: incompatible shape for a non-contiguous array
```

If I do a `reshape`, I get a copy (as shown by a totally different databuffer address):

```
In [305]: a2 = a1.reshape(-1)
In [306]: a2
Out[306]: 
array([  7,  91, 205,  21,  13, 251,  56, 211,  20, 154, 164,  64],
      dtype=uint8)
In [307]: a2.view('<u4')
Out[307]: array([ 365779719, 3543726861, 1084529172], dtype=uint32)
In [308]: a2.__array_interface__['data']
Out[308]: (37940512, False)
```

So you can view the same databuffer with different endedness, but you can't view individual bytes in a different order without either making a non-contiguous array, or making a copy.

---

`newbyteorder` docs say it is equivalent to:

```
arr.view(arr.dtype.newbytorder(new_order))
```

So `a.view('<u4').newbyteorder('>')` is the same as `a.view('<u4')`.  None of these changes `a`.

Answer (score 2):

The new byte order applied with `newbyteorder` is solely a property of the array's dtype; `a.newbyteorder("<")` returns a view of `a` with a little-endian dtype. It doesn't change the contents of memory, and it doesn't affect the array's shape or strides.

`ndarray.view` doesn't care about the original array's dtype, little-endian or big. It cares about the array's shape, strides, and actual memory content, none of which have changed.

Comment: So I can never combine two calls to `view`? (Or combine `newbyteorder` and `view` for that matter.) How do I get the `uint8` chunks in big-endian order without changing the memory, then?

Comment: @Jayjayyy: For one `uint32` value? `view` and slice-reverse. For an array of more than one `uint32`? You'll have to either add a new dimension or change the memory contents; the strides won't work out otherwise.

Comment: Okay, so I cannot make the `view` method "see the data as big-endian". Is this a limitation of the current implementation in NumPy or is this impossible altogether? What do you mean with `view` and slice-reverse? What do you mean with adding a new dimension?

Comment: @Jayjayyy Try `np.sum(a.newbyteorder('<'))` and also change sign (alternatively, try `a.newbyteorder('<').tolist()`). So, my answer to _"How do I get the uint8 chunks in big-endian order without changing the memory, then?"_ would be that you can accomplish that by _accessing_ the elements in the view.

Comment: @user2357112 Do you mean like this? When I have `a = np.array([123456789, 234567891, 345678912], dtype=np.uint32)` then I could use `a.view(np.uint8).reshape(-1, 4)[:, ::-1]`? Is this without changing the memory and without copying the array?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to [@user2357112's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50440455/8033585), [from documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.byteswapping.html#changing-byte-ordering):

> As you can imagine from the introduction, there are two ways you can affect the relationship between the byte ordering of the array and the underlying memory it is looking at:
>
> - Change the byte-ordering information in the array dtype so that it *interprets the underlying data as being in a different byte order*. This is the role of `arr.newbyteorder()`
> - *Change the byte-ordering of the underlying data*, leaving the dtype interpretation as it was. This is what `arr.byteswap()` does.

My emphasis in the quote above.

---

Other thought gathered from comments:

Since newbyteorder() is similar to view() in that it just changes the interpretation of the underlying data without changing the data, it appears that a view into a view is a view to the same (original) data. So, yes, you cannot "chain" views (well, you can... but it is always a view to the same original data).

> *How do I get the `uint8` chunks in big-endian order without changing the memory, then?*

Try `np.sum(a.newbyteorder('<'))` (alternatively, try `a.newbyteorder('<').tolist()`) and also change sign/endianness. So, my answer to the above question would be that you can't do that: either the memory is changed "in-place" with `byteswap()` or by making a copy of data to a new memory location when accessing the elements in the view.

Comment: Yes, that's what I read, so I thought I want to interpret the underlying data as being in a different byte order and then split it (it being the newly interpreted data) into `uint8` chunks. However, the interpretation doesn't affect the consecutive call to `view`...

Comment: @Jayjayyy Since `newbyteorder()` is similar to `view()` in that it just changes the _interpretation_ of the underlying data without changing this data, it appears that a view into a view is a view to the same (original) data. So, yes, you cannot "chain" views (well, you can but it is always a view to the same original data).